# Вызов функции Python раз в 10 минут и остановка этого процесса

Tags: python

Всем добрый день!
Есть кнопка в ТГ боте, человек нажимает на неё и должен пойти отсчет времени, раз в 10 минут должна вызываться функция set_support и так до тех пор, пока я не нажму кнопку снова.
Уже и со Sleep игрался и с asyncio. Пока не нашел решения, прошу помощи!
Использую Aiogram.
Есть кнопка:

```
support = KeyboardButton('Помощь')
```

Я её нажимаю, должен запуститься таймер и каждые 10 минут должна срабатывать функция:

```
def set_support(active_collector):
date = datetime.date.today()
title = 'Помощь'
order_number = '-'
sql_select_query = """SELECT Support FROM settings"""
cursor.execute(sql_select_query)
order_volume = cursor.fetchone()[0]  # обьём
coef = '0'
data = (date, active_collector, title, order_number, order_volume, coef)
cursor.executemany(
        """INSERT INTO archive(Date,name,title,order_number,order_volume,coef) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)""", (data,))
conn.commit()
print('Добавлено!')
```

Когда нажимаю кнопку ещё раз этот процесс должен прекратиться

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Укажите в вопросе какая конкретно библиотека для ТГ бота используется.

Comment: Указал и добавил код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью расписания создаете работу. Когда работа больше не нужна, отменяете её. Код обработчик кнопки я не знаю, поэтому написал в общем

```
import time
import threading
import schedule
import queue


def set_support(active_collector):
    date = datetime.date.today()
    title = 'Помощь'
    order_number = '-'
    sql_select_query = """SELECT Support FROM settings"""
    cursor.execute(sql_select_query)
    order_volume = cursor.fetchone()[0]  # обьём
    coef = '0'
    data = (date, active_collector, title, order_number, order_volume, coef)
    cursor.executemany(
            """INSERT INTO archive(Date,name,title,order_number,order_volume,coef) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)""", (data,))
    conn.commit()
    print('Добавлено!')


Mainjob = None
def run_scheduler(active_collector):
    Mainjob = schedule.every(10).minutes.do(set_support, active_collector = active_collector)
def off_scheduler():
    schedule.cancel_job(Mainjob)
    
def run_timer():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

thread = Thread(target = run_timer)
thread.start()
```

run_scheduler - запустить работу

off_scheduler - выключить работу

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло!